# Filas de DataTable Bootstrap en Una sola linea ASP.net MVC

Tags: bootstrap, asp.net-mvc, css3, mvc, razor

Quiero Que todas las filas esten en una linea.

Como podran Ver a continuacion, tengo Una vista donde recibo un datatable dinamico que fue alimentado por un Json, no conozco el nombre de las filas o columnas por lo que no puedo poner un ancho fijo a todas las columnas

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                @foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
                                {
                                    <th class="text-center">@col.Caption</th>
                                } 
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in Model.Rows)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    @foreach (var cell in row.ItemArray)
                                    {
                                        <td class="text-center" style="padding-top:0%; padding-bottom:0%;">@cell.ToString()</td>
                                    }
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

[image: Tabla Bootstrap con hasta 3 lineas en una fila]

Como pueden observar tengo columnas con hasta 3 Lineas en una fila. Existe una forma de yo auto Ajustar ese ancho. Sabiendo que cuando inserto las columnas aun no se que tamaño tendra esa columna.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo hay que Poner `<tr style="white-space:nowrap;">` en Cada `<tr></tr>` y listo. Gracias a los que Respondieron.

Answer (score 1):

Al dar estilo a cada `<td>` hazlo con el `width` al 100%:

```
style="padding-top:0%; padding-bottom:0%; width: 100%"
```

Para que finalmente quede tu línea `<td>` de esta forma:

```
<td class="text-center" style="padding-top:0%; padding-bottom:0%; width: 100%">@cell.ToString()</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Con `ColumnDefs` puedes definir varios parámetros de la tabla de **Datatables**, en el apartado de **[Related](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs#Related)** veras las posibles opciones que puedes configurar, en donde hasta al final encuentras [columns.width](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width)

Ejemplo:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "columnDefs": [
        { "width": "20%", "targets": 0 },
        { "width": "20%", "targets": [1,3] },
        //agregar un arreglo [0,n] tomara todas esas posisiones para darle el mismo ancho de 0 a n.
        { "width": "20%", "targets": 4 },
        { "width": "20%", "targets": 5 }
    ]
} );
```

o bien puedes darle el ancho directo al encabezado con:

```
<th class="text-center" width="20px">@col.Caption</th>
<th class="text-center" width="150px">@col.Caption</th>
...
```

Esto ultimo seria complicado en tu código.

Comment: Con esto Se Resolvio. Gracias de Todos modos por ayudar me.  <tr style="white-space:nowrap;">